# Sorting <li> tags

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I have a a  and I would like to sort my list alphabetically (I don't want caps to matter) according to a class named "name". How would I do this?

```
<ul class="column">
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="name" >Name of Item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>morecontent</td>
        <td>morecontent</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="name" >Another name of item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>morecontent</td>
        <td>morecontent</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: Uh. Is this a client-side or server-side scripting question? How are you sorting them? If client-side, on what event? If server-side, how are they generated? More info please.

Comment: Like meder say. I should provide more info. If this is generated, sort it first. Other wise, the easiest way is to use jQuery to sort it.

Comment: it is not generated i have all the tables in my page I wanted to use javascript to get the text in the name class and sort it from there. But im no good with javascript.

Comment: OK this was *just* asked yesterday (with a slightly different html structure). The accepted answer is *sweet*, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491678/sort-a-set-of-lis-alphanumerically/1491917#1491917

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using jQuery, this should do it:

```
function sort() {
    $($('ul.column>li').get().reverse()).each(function(outer) {
        var sorting = this;
        $($('ul.column>li').get().reverse()).each(function(inner) {
            if($('td.name', this).text().localeCompare($('td.name', sorting).text()) > 0) {
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The above is a little dense though, so if you want to understand what's going on, let's break it down line-by-line:

```
function sort() {

    //get each <li> which is a child of <ul class="column">
    //for each element in the results, execute a function
    //also, we reversed the order (e.g. start at the bottom and go up
    $($('ul.column>li').get().reverse()).each(function(outer) {

        //this is the current <li> we're running against
        var sorting = this;

        //get the same set of elements again in their current state,
        //so we can figure out where to put this one
        $($('ul.column>li').get().reverse()).each(function(inner) {

            //get the inner text of the <td class="name">
            //for the item we're trying to replace,
            //and for the current item in the inner loop
            //use localeCompare to compare the two strings alphabetically
            if($('td.name', this).text().localeCompare($('td.name', sorting).text()) > 0) {

                //if the one we're trying to sort goes after the current one
                //alphabetically, remove it from its current position
                //and insert it after the current one
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

We can make it a little more reusable by passing in the selector for the list and the key:

```
sort('ul.column>li', 'td.name');

function sort(list, key) {
    $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function(outer) {
        var sorting = this;
        $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function(inner) {
            if($(key, this).text().localeCompare($(key, sorting).text()) > 0) {
                this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Do keep in mind this requires jQuery, so you'll need a reference to it in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this function should be called at some point in the page *after* the list is written in the HTML.

Comment: Your solution is very flexible.

Comment: Hey @rexm, I know this post is pretty old, but I just stumbled over it. I tried this on a menu with multiple sub menus. It did work, but itgathered all li in the first sub menu. I can't think of a solution for this case, maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 3):

Mine answer is longer :p but work.

```
function SortLIs() {
    var ColumnUL = $("ul.column");
    var Columns  = $(ColumnUL).children("li");
     
    var ColumnNames    = new Array();
    var Columns_byName = new Array();
    var Columns_Count  = Columns.length;
    for(var i = 0; i <  Columns_Count; i++) {
        var aColumn = Columns[i];
        var aTD     = $(aColumn).find(".name");
        var aTDName = aTD.text();
        ColumnNames.push(aTDName);
        Columns_byName[aTDName] = aColumn;

        $(aColumn).remove();
    }
     
    ColumnNames.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a >  b) - (a <  b);
    });
     
    for(var i = 0; i <  Columns_Count; i++) {
        var aName = ColumnNames[i];
        ColumnUL.append(Columns_byName[aName]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  I saw you said that you are not good at JS. So here is the bigger picture for you.

(1) Add The following code to the header of the HTML. This will use jQuery library.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

(2) Add the '`sortLIs`' code just right after the above code

```
<script>
<!--
function SortILs() {
    ...
}
-->
</script>
```

(3.1) If you want the sorting to begin at the load time. Add this right after the above code.

```
<script>
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    SortILs();
});
-->
</script>
```

(3.2) Otherwise, you call the function from an event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work if there are nested lists inside the list to be sorted.

Comment: You are right. I've use to use 'find', I will change it to children. Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach, stealing ideas from the other answers given so far (also requiring jQuery):

```
function sort(elementSelector, valueSelector, ascending) {
  var sign = ascending ? -1 : 1;
  var elements = jQuery(elementSelector);
  elements.each(function() {
    this.sortKey = jQuery(valueSelector, this).text();
  });
  var sorted = elements.get();
  sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
    var keyA = a.sortKey;
    var keyB = b.sortKey;
    return sign * ((keyA < keyB) - (keyA > keyB));
  });
  elements.parent().append(sorted);
}

sort('.column>li', '.name', true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just seconding the jQuery response above, have a look at this tutorial:
http://www.shopdev.co.uk/blog/sortable-lists-using-jquery-ui/

For semantics, you might be better off also placing the classname inside the actual `<li>` tag.

The use of a table inside a list aside though, you may want to post an example page to help further.

Comment: Thanks, I already Im using JQuery so this will be easy to add. :)