# Sorting a listview using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Here the code is only sorting the li items in ascending order.How to sort in both ascending and descending order by using this code [Sorting <li> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496033/sorting-li-tags)

```
 function sort(list, key) {
         $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function (outer) {
             var sorting = this;
             $($(list).get().reverse()).each(function (inner) {
                 if ($(key, this).text().localeCompare($(key, sorting).text()) > 0) {
                     this.parentNode.insertBefore(sorting.parentNode.removeChild(sorting), this);
                 }
             });
         });
     }
```

and

```
window.onload = function () {
         var desc = false;
         document.getElementById("stCodeDSC").onclick = function () {
             //             sortUnorderedList("list3", desc);

             sort('ul.conn1>li', 'td.code1');
             desc = !desc;
             return false;
         }
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT: If i give `<0` then it is sorting in descending order..

EDIT2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var desc = false;
         document.getElementById("stCodeDSC").onclick = function () {
             //             sortUnorderedList("list3", desc);

             sort('ul.conn>li', 'td.code');

             desc = !desc;
             return false;
         }
         document.getElementById("stNameDSC").onclick = function () {
             //             sortUnorderedList("list3", desc);

             sort('ul.conn>li', 'td.name');
             desc = !desc;
             return false;
         }
     });
```

Comment: FYI: When you have jQuery, you do never use `window.onload`.

Comment: may i know the reason for that??

Comment: Because jQuery provides an easy way to attach an event handler to the load event that does not require overwriting the global one. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: When you have jQuery, you also do not use `onclick` or any of the other "native" `onXYZ` event handlers. I suggest you spend a little time reading about jQuery, because that's not how it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

How about a jQuery plugin:

```
function elemLocaleCompare(left, right) {
    return $(left).text().localeCompare($(right).text());
}

$.fn.extend({
    sortList: function(order) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $list = $(this),
                li = $list.children("li").toArray().sort(elemLocaleCompare);

            if (li.length == 0) return true;

            order = order || $list.data("nextOrder") || "asc";

            if (order == "asc")
                $list.append(li).data("nextOrder", "desc");
            else
                $list.append(li.reverse()).data("nextOrder", "asc");
        });
    }
});
```

Use like:

```
$("ol").sortList("asc");

// or...
$("#someList").sortList();  // initial sort order, "asc" is default

$("#someButton").click(function () {
  $("#someList").sortList();     // no argument -> toggle sort order
});
​
```

Comment: <td class="code" style="width: 50%;">                                                            <%# Eval("code") %>                                                                </td>
                                                                                        <td class="name" style="width: 50%;">
                                                                                             <%# Eval("Name") %>
                                                                                        </td>

Comment: Here i need to sort based on code in a button click and name in another button click

Comment: look at my EDIT2..I need like that

Comment: @bala3569 I somehow thought you wanted to sort list items. You might want to use the [jQuery tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/) for your problem. There is no use in re-inventing the wheel for this.