# Dojo Drag-Drop Issue: Sorting items in target DND container

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop, dojo-dnd

My JavaScript code is as below

//I have a Json:

```
var jsonRoles = {"roles": [
                            {"roleId": "1", "roleName": "role1", "roleDesc": "This is role1"},
                            {"roleId": "2", "roleName": "role2", "roleDesc": "This is role2"},
                            {"roleId": "3", "roleName": "role3", "roleDesc": "This is role3"}
                        ]
                    };
```

//To get the all role name listed in DND container i used the for loop:

```
var results="";
                    for(var i=0;i<jsonRoles.roles.length;i++){
                        results += '<div class="dojoDndItem">' + jsonRoles.roles[i].roleName  + '</div>';
                    }
```

//The two content panes are as below for two blocks for drag and drop

```
var assignPermissionToUser1 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        //splitter:true,
                        region: "left",
                        style: "background-color: white;width: 200px; height: 500px",
                        content:'<div>' + '<label>Roles</label>' + '</div>' + '<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" id="rolelistNode" class="container">' + 
                                '<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" class="dojoDndItem movableContainer">' + '</div>' + results +
                                '</div>'       
                    });
                    var assignPermissionToUser2 = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
                        //splitter:true,
                        region: "right",
                        style: "background-color: white;width: 200px; height: 500px",
                        content:'<div>' + '<label>Users</label>' + '</div>' +'<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container">' +
                                '<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" class="dojoDndItem movableContainer">' + '</div>' +
                                '</div>'            
                    });
```

//Border Container

```
            innerBorderContainerAsAccordion = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({
                id: "innerBorderContainerAsAccordion",
                region: "center",
                style: "background-color: white;width: 175px; height: 550px"
            });
```

//Set the contents of the border container

```
    innerBorderContainerAsAccordion.addChild(assignPermissionToUser1);
    innerBorderContainerAsAccordion.addChild(assignPermissionToUser2);
```

**My question is if I drag an element from on DND container to the another, how can it arrange/sort the items by their ID or by alphabet etc?**

For example (below images)

**Initial states of both container**
[image]

**After drag and drop some items to second DND container**
[image]

**How can I force fully sort the items of second DND container like this:**
[image]

Can anyone help? Thank you

Comment: Well Then I think you can get your answer here..
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496033/sorting-li-tags

Comment: I told you that I cant use jQuery. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @AbdulAziz yeah. Learn dojo and rewrite it in dojo.

Comment: @Esailija I used dojo, whats the point?

Comment: @AbdulAziz the point is that you can implement the jQuery answers in dojo yourself. Or are you only capable of copypasting directly working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code, and this time its javascript

```
 function sortList(listId) {
        // Get the ul object
        var oUl = document.getElementById(listId);
        /* Perform a Bubble Sort on the list items */
        for (var i in oUl.childNodes) {
            var x = oUl.childNodes[i];
            for (var j in oUl.childNodes) {
                var y = oUl.childNodes[j];
                if ((x.innerText != 'undefined' || y.innerText != 'undefined') && x.innerText > y.innerText) {
                    // Skip if x is already the first list item
                    if (oUl.firstChild != x)
                        oUl.insertBefore(y, x);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /* Define innerText for Mozilla based browsers */
    if ((typeof HTMLElement != 'undefined') && (HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__ != 'undefined')) {
        HTMLElement.prototype.__defineGetter__("innerText", function () {
            var r = this.ownerDocument.createRange();
            r.selectNodeContents(this);
            return r.toString();
        });

    }


    window.onload = function () {
        sortList("ID_of_Your_ul_tag");
    }
```

Comment: innerText is undefined: for JS foreach style for loops, check against list.hasOwnProperty(iter)). E.g. ul.childNodes == { '0':Element, '1':Element, length: integer, getElementsByClassName: function ... }

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your dndContainer has className dojoDndItem, this will fail if you do not apply a unique className to the 'real items' to distinquish those from their parent.

And im not sure why, but you create 4 x dndSource's (movableContainer?)

Best practice is to give your dndContainer an ID, following assumes that items have a class=='roleItem' and dndContainer has id=='targetContainer'

```
var dndC = dojo.byId('targetContainer', assignPermissionToUser2.domNode);
dojo.query( ".roleDndItem",  dndC )
  .sort(function( a,b ) {
      // can check for whatever property on the item here
      // for complete numerical sort you need a comperator (parseFloat works)
      return (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML 
          ? 0 : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1));
  })
  .forEach(function(a, idx) {
      console.log(a.innerHTML);  // output should be alphanumerically 
      // sorted by lowest == (idx=0)
      // idx 0 inserts be childNode[0] (firstChild), 
      // idx 1 before (new) second child
      dndC.insertBefore(a, dndC.childNodes[idx]);
});
```

Dojo hands out what appears to be a oneliner but is so much more to it. However you only need to tweak two lines, sort-return and node-reference dndC.

```
dojo.query(".roleItem",  dndC ).sort(
    function( a,b ) {  
        return (a.innerHTML == b.innerHTML ? 0 : (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1));
    }
).forEach(
    function(a, idx) { 
        dndC.insertBefore(a, dndC.childNodes[idx]);  
}); //^^
```

To connect do something similar to

```
dojo.subscribe("dnd/drop", function() { /* */ });
```

or for a programatically created dndSource;

```
dojo.connect(dndSourceObj, "onDrop", function() { /* */ });
```

Comment: no, query works on selectors which mainly is constructed by classnames.. you could give each role-item-div the same ID but then it'd look like query("#roleDndItemID"). Set a roleItem classname for this construct: `results += '<div class="dojoDndItem">' + jsonRoles.roles[i].roleName  + '</div>';`

Comment: consider ids and classnames: `<ol dojotype="dojo.dnd.Source" id="wishlistNode" class="container">
<li class="dojoDndItem">Wrist watch</li>
<li class="dojoDndItem">Life jacket</li>
<li class="dojoDndItem">Toy bulldozer</li>
<li class="dojoDndItem">Vintage microphone</li>
<li class="dojoDndItem">TIE fighter</li>
</ol>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
jQuery.fn.sortElements = (function(){
    var sort = [].sort;
    return function(comparator, getSortable) {
        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};
        var placements = this.map(function(){     
            var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );     
            return function() {
                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }     
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);
            };
        });
        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });
    };
})();
```

Assuming the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

You could sort the items alphabetically like so:

```
$('li').sortElements(function(a, b){
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : -1;
});
```

That would result in:

```
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I cant use jQuery. Don't ask me why... Ok I tell you, our company won't allow it.