# Dojo.Query Issue: getting elements of a class using `dojo.query` by class name

Tags: javascript, class, dojo

Related to my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10382901/1134935), I am facing trouble getting all elements I want to get all elements of a class using `dojo.query`
my code is as below;

```
var jsonRoles = {"roles": [
                            {"roleId": "1", "roleName": "role1", "roleDesc": "This is role1"},
                            {"roleId": "2", "roleName": "role2", "roleDesc": "This is role2"},
                            {"roleId": "3", "roleName": "role3", "roleDesc": "This is role3"}
                        ]
                    };
                    var results="";
                    for(var i=0;i<jsonRoles.roles.length;i++){
                        results += '<div class="dojoDndItem ">' + '<span style="visibility: hidden">' + jsonRoles.roles[i].roleId + '</span>' + jsonRoles.roles[i].roleName  + '</div>';
                    }
                    var list = dojo.query(".dojoDndItem");
```

I want to store elements with class name `dojoDndItem` in variable "**list**" but when i inspect the "**list**" in **firebug**, it gives me **"[]" (empty array)**. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`dojo.query`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/query.html) returns an array of matching [DOM nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247) from the page based on a CSS selector.

The variable `results` in your question is just a string with text like:

```
<div class="dojoDndItem"><span style="visibility: hidden">...
```

It's *just a string*. It's not an array of DOM elements, nor have you added any new elements to the page DOM itself, so unless there are pre-existing elements with the `dojoDndItem` class, empty array `[]` is the correct result.

Comment: Can you explain by some suggested solution for this issue?

Comment: Solution *to what*? Did you want to add the HTML in `results` to the page? Did you want to create an array of DOM elements unattached to the page?`