# sorting LI commands under OL

Tags: javascript, sorting, alphabetical

Anyway to sort this alphabetically(In javascript preferably)?

```
        <ol>
    <li><a id="a_title_4" onclick="SetCurrent(4);return false;" href="#">Mp_Dungeon_p</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_5" onclick="SetCurrent(5);return false;" href="#">Mp_Sonic</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_6" onclick="SetCurrent(6);return false;" href="#">Mp_Trial_2_p</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_7" onclick="SetCurrent(7);return false;" href="#">Mp_Spacestation</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_8" onclick="SetCurrent(8);return false;" href="#">Mp_GP_Jump</a></li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: And is this HTML being dynamically generated somewhere?  That would be the level at which to sort it.  If it's not dynamically generated, you can just do it manually once.

Comment: Why are there `td` elements? They don't belong outside of a `tr`.

Comment: If you wrote them and they don't change, I suggest using Vocabulary. It's the latest buzz, don't know if all browsers supports it

Comment: @Damien: care to share a link?  Not really googlable...

Comment: -_-'. @Jonah Sorry, irony gone wrong. This messages will autodelete in 30 seconds.

Comment: @Damien: but what were you talking about :) ?

Comment: @Jonah: He means, "If the links are static, just order them yourself."

Answer (score 2):

PHP is overkill here. Just check the answers to this question [Sort a set of li tags alphanumerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491678/sort-a-set-of-lis-alphanumerically)

Comment: If he's already using PHP to generate dynamic content on the page, it's not overkill at all.

Comment: I see no PHP code, no PHP tag and no mention of PHP in his question. However I do see a Javascript tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple PHP solution:**

```
<?php
    // sample link data
    $links = array(
        4=>'Mp_Dungeon_p',
        5=>'Mp_Sonic',
        6=>'Mp_Trial_2_p',
        7=>'Mp_Spacestation',
        8=>'Mp_GP_Jump'
    );

    // sort $links
    asort($links);

    // output link list
    echo '<ol>' . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($links as $id=>$text) {
        echo '  <li><a id="a_title_' . $id . '" onclick="SetCurrent(' . $id . ');return false;" href="#">' . $text . '</a></li>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</ol>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<ol>
    <li><a id="a_title_4" onclick="SetCurrent(4);return false;" href="#">Mp_Dungeon_p</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_8" onclick="SetCurrent(8);return false;" href="#">Mp_GP_Jump</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_5" onclick="SetCurrent(5);return false;" href="#">Mp_Sonic</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_7" onclick="SetCurrent(7);return false;" href="#">Mp_Spacestation</a></li>
    <li><a id="a_title_6" onclick="SetCurrent(6);return false;" href="#">Mp_Trial_2_p</a></li>
</ol>
```